# Trying to display field heading only when field is not empty

Tags: php

domicile is field in record set.

the problem is that Domicile heading is not showing where I want it to print. Its showing nothing.

Comment: Adding a PHP tag to this question would have been better.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure? If $rows_Recordset1['domicile'] is *not* empty then it is the opposite of what you want. Try change

> empty($rows_Recordset1['domicile'])

to

> empty($rows_Recordset1['domicile'])

Hope it helps